# how to put text on left bottom with css and ionic

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

In my design, i want to put text on left bottom of the screen. Look at the image

[image]

fixed content text should be at highlighted place

Here is my code

```
<template>
  <IonPage>

    <ion-content :fullscreen="true" id="start" class="background">

      <div id="product_background" >
        <Topbar />
        <div class="container">
        <ion-text color="" class="top-left">
        <h1>ARTICS PRO</h1>

      </ion-text>
      <ion-text color="" class="top-left2">
        <p>Steelseries</p>
      </ion-text>
       <ion-text color="" class="bottom-right">
        <p>ARTICS 7</p>

      </ion-text>
      <ion-text color="" class="bottom-right2">
        <p>Steelseries</p>

      </ion-text>
         <img :src="require('@/assets/headset_mockup.png')" style="height:105vw;width:100vw"/>
     </div>
       <div slot="bottom" style="">
        <h1>Fixed Content</h1>
      </div>
      </div>

    </ion-content>

  </IonPage>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { IonContent, IonPage,IonText  } from '@ionic/vue';
import Topbar from '../Resources/Topbar.vue';
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';

export default  {
  name: 'Index',
  components: {IonContent, IonPage, Topbar,IonText },
  setup() {

    return {
      router: useRouter(),
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style>
ion-content.background{

    --background: transparent url('../../assets/product_background.png') 0 0/100% 92% no-repeat;

    }
 #product_background{
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 20px;
 }
.bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 14px;
  right: 16px;
}
.bottom-right2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 16px;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  left: 8px;
}
.top-left2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  left: 6px;
}
</style>
```

I have also keep in mind that it should be responsive for all mobile devices. So its behavior should be responsive so it can suit all the mobile phone devices.
How I can achieve this?

Comment: I formatted your markup for you in your last question. Please do the same here. Improperly formatted (nested) markup is much more difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve that you can use `position: fixed` and `z-index` on your div and set the div to the place you'd like.

Eg:

In your html:

```
<div class="fixed-content">
  <h1>Fixed Content</h1>
</div>
```

In your css:

```
.fixed-content {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Remember, to `z-index` work, you need to set a position to the element and for `position: fixed` work correctly you need to set `position: relative` to the parent image.

This way **fixed-content** will be at the left bottom relative to the parent image.